# How to pass a text in a query instead of objectId in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to pass an plain text value instead of ObjectId in a query string like this: **127.0.0.1:3000/trips?from=mumbai&to=ahmedabad&date=2022-06-02**

*Instead of* **127.0.0.1:3000/trips?from=6295f0986f9e32990d8b3488&to=6295f0c06f9e32990d8b348b&date=2022-06-02**.

I am getting the result whenever I pass the object ID as a value but when I pass the plain text value I am getting this error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "mumbai" (type string) at path "Location.to" for model "Route"

I have referenced Location table into the route table like this:

```
const routeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    Location: {
      from: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Location",
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Location",
        required: true,
      },
    },
    busId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Bus",
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Here is the Location table:

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    location: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
      },
      subLocation: [String],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Here is the GET request to trip data.

```
router.get("/trips", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.from || !req.query.to || !req.query.date) {
    return res.send({
      error: "Please enter the data to get the trip",
    });
  }
  const { from, to, date } = req.query;

  const routes = await Route.find({
    "Location.from": from,
    "Location.to": to,
    date,
  }).populate({
      path: "Location.from Location.to",
      select: "-location.subLocation -_id -createdAt -updatedAt -__v",
    }).select(["-_id", "-busId", "-createdAt", "-updatedAt", "-__v"]);

  return !routes ? res.status(500).send() : res.status(200).send(routes);
});
```

I want to pass a plain text as query value instead of objectID and still want to get the result.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: But how can I accept non working answers. It will create negative impact on the users

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the query as text then remove `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` as type from `Route` model and set type as `String`. If any of the keys have type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` then MongoDB only accepts an alphanumeric string of 24 characters. Otherwise, it throws a casting error.

Comment: Then I am getting an empty array not the intended result